# Excel - Match data from column and get the value next to it

Tags: excel, vlookup

Is there a formula that match data, get the value next to it, and then post that value into another cell?

**This is what my excel sheet looks like:**

```
Sheet A

Column A   |   Column B   |   Column C   |   Column D
----------------------------------------------------------
    Bob                         John           Cat
    John                        Sue            Dog
    Sue                         Bob            Duck
```

John owns a cat, Sue owns a dog, and Bob owns a duck. I want to match Column A to Column C and then grab the value right next to Column C and then put that value back into Column B.

**This is the result that I want:**

```
Sheet A

Column A   |   Column B   |   Column C   |   Column D
----------------------------------------------------------
    Bob          Duck           John           Cat
    John         Cat            Sue            Dog
    Sue          Dog            Bob            Duck
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [VLOOKUP()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php) function. Enter the formula in cell B1 and pull it down. You might need to edit your range aswell.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;$C$1:$D$10;2;0)
```

*you might need to change `;` with `,` depending on your language settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vlookup (as you've tagged your question) but combining index and match is a much more versatile way of doing this (it doesn't require the the lookup row to be on the left side and is also more efficient).

Assuming row 1 contains headers, you could use the following formula in column B:

```
=index($D$2:$D$4,match(A2,$C$2:$C$4,0))
```